# Это тот/те/та()... Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Это тот (самый)() старый порядок.

Как в таких случаях ставятся знаки препинания?
Интонационно после "тот" -- пауза.

Еще пример:

"Это та() старая гвардия".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько помнится, в таком случае запятая ставится, чтобы разъяснить смысл предыдущего определения (Это тот (какой именно?),самый старый порядок (предыдущий порядок был не таким старым) Это та (какая именно?),старая гвардия(другая гвардия была не старая). Розенталь приводит подобный пример: Построили новый, каменный дом (перед этим построили дом не каменный, а их другого стройматериала)

Answer (score 3):

Согласно действующим правилам пунктуации возможны 2 варианта:

*Это тот самый старый порядок.* (Определение после указательного местоимения тесно примыкает к нему и не имеет значения уточнения.)

*Это тот самый, старый, порядок.* (Если рассматривать *старый* как уточнение.)

Вариант с одной запятой невозможен, так это не пояснительное согласованное определение, которое не выделяется второй запятой, а уточнение, а оно всегда выделяется запятыми с двух сторон.

Правило звучит так: **уточняющие** определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений *этот, тот, такой* и др. (в том числе субстантивированных), например: *Чичиков немного озадачился таким, отчасти резким, определением* (Гоголь).

Comment: "Ну а если это та, старая болезнь, разросшаяся галлюцинация, слышимая лишь ему одному"? "Та, старая, чуть не развалившаяся статуя, с попорченной щекой, с прогнившими в алебастре щелями от ветхости..." "Мы ведь еще застали те, старые английские деньги".  Можно и дальше продолжить.

Comment: Авторская пунктуация никогда не была эталоном. Я говорю о действующих правилах.

Comment: Авторская пунктуация должна быть эталоном, на основании которого следует составлять правила чиновникам от орфографии, а не художнику слова подобает работать по их формулярам. Думаю, что наше общество уже достигло такого уровня развития, когда по правилам следует  писать в младшей школе, а уж после 5-го класса только по грамматике.

Comment: София, ну буря в стакане воды. Когда это правила мешали авторам самовыражаться? И как может быть эталоном хаос авторской пунктуации, притом что большинство авторов еще и малограмотные? А Розенталь все равно гений. И реформа пунктуации когда-нибудь будет. Справедливость восторжествует.

Comment: Добавим еще немного "неграмотных", которым Ваше Правило мешает самовыражаться: "В непонятном волнении  оглянется вокруг себя и увидит, что она одна: та, другая старуха исчезла" (В. Распутин).  "И тот, другой язык Марта поняла и стала  говорить по-немецки"(Ю. Тынянов).  "Все равно этот день кончится, как прожит и забыт тот, прежний день (А. Платонов). Какая вам нужна реформа? Одни Правила заменить другими Правилами? Розенталь был гений по интуиции. Надо не зубрить правила, а решать задачи, как Розенталь, но при этом соотносить решение с основными принципами - вот и вся реформа.

Answer (score 2):

Кроме правил, есть еще вариант: изучаем грамматику и подтверждаем ее примерами из Национального корпуса.В результате получаем следующее: при наличии местоимения ТОТ возможны ТРИ ВАРИАНТА постановки знаков препинания.

1) Неоднородные отношения (нет запятой):
"Я не изучал ТОТ СТАРЫЙ дом, где жил, как материал для рассказа" (К. Паустовский). Это самый распространенный вариант.

2) Пояснительные отношения (обособление): "ТОТ, СТАРЫЙ, сразу же поднялся и за нами (Ю. Домбровский). "Ефремовский кабинет ― еще тот, старый, с предбанничком, где сидела Раиса Викторовна, знаменитый его секретарь" (М. Рощин). "Через три дня Константин принес те, старые, пять тысяч и новые пятнадцать" (В. Тучков). Этот вариант встречается не часто.

3) Пояснительные отношения однородного типа (ставится запятая): "Мне, как в кино, показали ТОТ, СТАРЫЙ мир и этот" (В. Березин).

Answer (score 1):

Подробнее об этом - здесь.  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm    (Р озенталь: Справочник по русскому языку).